# How to change type of a field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Here are my questions:

1. How to change all the string type "NULL" in one field to nulls in null type in MongoDB?
2. How to change all the string type "20xx-xx-xx" in one field to date type in MongoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
db.foo.insert({bar: "NULL", date: "2012-11-30"})
db.foo.insert({bar: "NULL", date: "2010-09-21"})
db.foo.insert({bar: "NOTNULL", date: "2010-09-21"})
```

> How to change all the string type "NULL" in one field to nulls in null type in MongoDB?

```js
db.foo.update({bar: "NULL"}, {$set: {bar: null}}, {multi: true})
```

> How to change all the string type "20xx-xx-xx" in one field to date type in MongoDB?

```js
db.foo.find({date: {$exists: true}}).forEach(
   function(doc) {doc.date = new Date(doc.date); db.foo.save(doc)}
)
```

**Edit**

If for some reason you have problem with default parsing it can be done manually:

Lets assume you have document like this

```js
doc = {date: "2012-01-30"}
```

First split string representation on hypens and cast each to integer

```js
dateArray = doc.date.split('-').map(function(s) { return parseInt(s); })
```

Substract 1 from month field (months in js are counted from 0)

```js
dateArray[1] -= 1
```

Now we can create new date object. There are whoever some things to consider. When you parse string to date, there is assumption that the string represents UTC date when you use this:

```js
new Date("2012-01-30")
```

You will get

```js
ISODate("2012-01-30T00:00:00Z")
```

You can also create `Date` constructor like this

```js
new Date(dateArray[0], dateArray[1], dateArray[2])
```

but it will assume that data is using local tz so and in my case (GMT+1) I get:

```js
ISODate("2012-01-29T23:00:00Z")
```

If it is not what you want you can set some fields manually:

```js
date = new Date(0) // ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
date.setUTCFullYear(dateArray[0], dateArray[1], dateArray[2])
```

Now date looks like this:

```js
ISODate("2012-01-30T00:00:00Z")
```

Wrapping it all together:

```js
db.foo.find({date: {$exists: true}}).forEach(
   function(doc) {
       dateArray = doc.date.split('-').map(function(s) { return parseInt(s); });
       dateArray[1] -= 1;

       date = new Date(0);
       date.setUTCFullYear(dateArray[0], dateArray[1], dateArray[2]);

       doc.date = date;
       db.foo.save(doc)
    }
)
```

Comment: I just found an error. All the date change to 1970-01-01 after I used your solution to change the format. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You can parse date manually - I've posted an edit with explanation but I think you are trying to access non-existing field. Since `new Date(null)` is equivalent to `new Date(0)` it will give you `ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")`